# Parsing 2D matrix: "[[1,2][3,4]]"

Tags: beginner, haskell, matrix

I feel I am over-complicating things, and that there should be a succinct way to achieve this - perhaps using concepts I have not learnt - or some prelude function I have missed out on.

How can I improve this?

```
data Mat2x2 = MkMat2x2 Integer Integer Integer Integer
  deriving (Show, Eq)


-- modified versions of preludes readParanthesis
readBrackets :: ReadS a -> ReadS a
readBrackets g = mandatory
                 where mandatory r = do
                              ("[", s) <- lex r
                              (x,t)    <- g s
                              ("]", u) <- lex t
                              return (x,u)

readInt :: String -> Maybe (Integer, String)
readInt s = listToMaybe ((reads :: String -> [(Integer, String)]) s)

-- greedy consumption of comma separated values and returns them as list and remaining string, ex:
-- parseCsv readInt "2,3,5,2"
-- ([2,3,5,2],"")
parseCsv :: (String -> Maybe (a, String)) -> String -> ([a], String)
parseCsv f s = case (f s) of
                        Nothing          -> ([], s)
                        Just (x,(',':r)) -> (x : (nextXs r), (nextR r))
                        Just (x,r)       -> ([x], r)
                      where nextXs ns = fst (parseCsv f ns)
                            nextR  ns = snd (parseCsv f ns)

-- reads an arbitrary length vector "[1,2,3,...N]" -> Just [1,2,3...,N]
readVec :: String -> Maybe ([Integer], String)
readVec s = listToMaybe (readBrackets ((:[]) . parseCsv readInt) s) -- note: (:[]) is operator making a list of one element

readVec2 :: String -> Maybe ((Integer, Integer), String)
readVec2 s = case readVec s of
                Just ((a:[b]), r)  -> Just ((a,b), r)
                Just (_, _)        -> Nothing
                Nothing            -> Nothing

read2Vec2 :: String -> Maybe (((Integer, Integer),(Integer,Integer)), String)
read2Vec2 s = case readVec2 s of
                    Nothing          -> Nothing
                    Just ((a,b), r1) -> case readVec2 r1 of
                                            Nothing          -> Nothing
                                            Just ((c,d), r2) -> Just (((a,b),(c,d)), r2)

readMat2x2 :: String -> Maybe (Mat2x2, String)
readMat2x2 s = case listToMaybe (readBrackets (maybeToList . read2Vec2) s) of
                    Nothing                 -> Nothing
                    Just (((a,b),(c,d)), r) -> Just ((MkMat2x2 a b c d), r)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many improvements are possible.

First, you shouldn't use `ReadS` and other rudumentary `Prelude` parsing function for anything but exercises. Use parsing libraries from Hackage instead. `parsec` is a good library to start with, if you are not sure of which one to use.

Second, if it is an exersise, you can avoid long chains of `Nothing` matches by using `Maybe` monad. I reimplemented `read2Vec2` for example:

```
read2Vec2 :: String -> Maybe (((Integer, Integer),(Integer,Integer)), String)
read2Vec2 s = do
    ((a,b), r1) <- readVec2 s
    ((c,d), r2) <- readVec2 r1
    Just (((a,b),(c,d)), r2)
```

Third, you can avoid passing unparsed input around by keeping it in the `State` monad. At this point our code will do what `parsec` does :) except `parsec` does it better.

If you want to stay with your current approach then `readBrackets` can be shortened:

```
readBrackets :: ReadS a -> ReadS a
readBrackets g r = do
    ("[", s) <- lex r
    (x,t)    <- g s
    ("]", u) <- lex t
    return (x,u)
```

Here is full parser using `parsec`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Control.Applicative

data Mat2x2 = MkMat2x2 Integer Integer Integer Integer
  deriving (Show, Eq)

parseMat2x2 = parse mat2x2 "(unknown)" 

nat = read <$> many1 digit 

mat2x2 = do
    string "[["
    d1 <- nat
    char ','
    d2 <- nat
    string "]["
    d3 <- nat
    char ','
    d4 <- nat
    string "]]"
    return $ MkMat2x2 d1 d2 d3 d4

main = print $ parseMat2x2 "[[2,2][3,4]]"
```

The parser can be made less strict if necessary. For example, current parser doesn't accept any whitespace. And for a better performance you could try parsec with a lexer stage (current code avoids lexer altogether).

For ultimate performance you should use `alex` and `happy` tools, which are haskell's `lex` and `yacc` respectively.

Comment: Many thanks for this! I am right now on lecture 5 on CIS194 (not taking the course) - so I'll have to revisit this answer once I have had an introduction to Monads. Great with advice on tools/libs/performance as well. Thanks.